# Using JSON.decode razor webhelper with a number node in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I'm using the JSON razor web helper (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538324%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to decode a JSON string I have with multiple nested nodes.

I used the JSON.Decode method fine on another project, but on this project my JSON source string has nested nodes that start with a number and I'm having issues.

My JSON string looks something like

```
myJSONString="
{
Foo1: ‘data’,
‘Foo2:’  {
    ‘123':{
        ‘goodStuff’:{ [
                    {
                      boo1: ‘Data1’,
                      boo2: ‘Data2’
                    }
                    ] }
          }
         }
}   "
```

Normally I would do:

```
var decodedJsonString = Json.Decode(myJSONString) <br>
```

and access data like:

```
foreach(var p in decodedJsonString.Foo2.123.goodStuff)
{ 
   p.boo1; <br>
   p.boo2; <br>
}
```

Normally this worked fine for me, but I get an error that it doesn't like the *.123.* part, since the node starts with a number, rather then a letter. The inline error is "Identifier expected". If I run the webpage the server error is that it: " ) Expected ".

Any suggestions? Thank you!

I can get around this by using a lot of foreach loops like:

```
foreach( var p in decodedJsonString.Foo2)
{ 
   var k = p.Value;
   if(p.Key.Equals("123"))
  {
    foreach(var j in k)
    {
     //etc
    }
  }
}
```

Just not sure how to make this a decoded JSON object that I can reference it again like decodedJsonString.Foo2.123.goodStuff

Appreciate any assistance. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
foreach(var p in decodedJsonString.Foo2['123'].goodStuff)
```

Comment: That basically works had to use "" instead     foreach(var p in decodedJsonString.Foo2["123"].goodStuff).   Thank you very much!